# biblatex: How to suppress back references for certain citations?

Tags: biblatex, floats, conditionals, back-referencing

When using BibTeX's standard citation commands, such as `\cite`, typically back references are generated (if enabled) in the bibliography pointing back to the place of citation. That's a nice feature. However, I would like to suppress these back references for certain citations, such as in figure or table captions. I don't want these to appear as back references in the bibliography.

I have found an identical [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.text.tex/zQplpg53KZE) on `comp.text.tex`, it is unanswered there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the boolean switch `backtracker` to `false` inside `figure` and `table` environments. (`biblatex` already does this for the ToC and similar lists.)

Note: `\AtBeginEnvironment` is an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) command, and `etoolbox` is loaded by `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\boolfalse{backtracker}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\boolfalse{backtracker}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure \autocite{B02}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does the trick. Having another look at the `BibLaTeX` manual, I found the `\backtrackerfalse` command, which seems to be the same thing. Including it in a `\AtBeginEnvironment` directive appears to be a good idea, too.